# Sending Temporary data to multiple partial views from view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm wondering if there is a good way to do this. I'm currently trying to send some temporary data to multiple partial views being called from the same view page in my MVC application.

I'm currently attempting to do this with TempData but I can see my understanding is limited as it is only going through for one partial request. What method do I need to use to filter out to all of my partials?

**Main View Page:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main View Page";

    TempData["ReturnUrl"] = Request.Url.OriginalString.ToString();
}

@Html.Partial("_StatusTable1")
@Html.Partial("_StatusTable2")
@Html.Partial("_StatusTable3")
@Html.Partial("_StatusTable4")
@Html.Partial("_StatusTable5")
```

**Partial View Example:**

```
@{
    var temp = TempData["ReturnUrl"]; // temp is null on all partials except the first
}

// Partial View Code ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use ViewBag

Comment: @Dismissile Won't ViewBag do the same thing just go out to one of the partials and that is it?

Comment: You don't need to use `TempData` and should be favouring strongly typed view models. `TempData` is there for redirection, which is why it's cleared after the first access.

Comment: @tokyo0709 no...TempData is meant to be accessed once like David mentioned. ViewBag has no such restriction. Although I agree strongly typed models are preferred. But if you don't want to create strongly typed models, you can use ViewBag. I believe you could also maybe change TempData["ReturnUrl"] to ViewData["ReturnUrl"]

Answer (score 0):

In your main view page call the partiel views like that

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", TempData["ReturnUrl"])
```

I think that even this would work.

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", TempData)
```

Comment: Won't work. As soon as he accesses TempData once, it is gone.

Comment: Then assign it to a variable and pass it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from TempData like this. ReturnUrl Value will retained across all the Partial Views

```
@{
    var temp = TempData.Peek("ReturnUrl");
}
```

// Partial View Code

Comment: Though technically this will work, it does promote wrong usage of the TempData storage bag. ViewBag or typed datastore would be a better fit for this specific use-case.